# g++ 4.6.3 reading contents of a file into string parsing ambiguity

Tags: c++, g++

I would like to read the contents of a ifstream

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream stream;
std::vector<char> buf(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

But then when I say:

```
if(buf.size())
...
```

I get an error

```
error: request for member 'size' in 'buf', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<char, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)())'
```

So the compiler thinks I am declaring a function instead of a `vector<char>`. How can I make it work?

I compile with `-std=c++0x` with `g++-4.6.3`

This question is more about parsing disambiguation than reading of a file.

Comment: I think is is a case of MVP, IIRC the fix for this is to wrap the 2nd parameter in parentheses.

Comment: Related: [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @sashoalm Thats an incorrect duplicate, the problem is not how to read the file, its a quirk of the language where that declaration is seen as a function not an object of type std::vector<char>

Comment: Indeed, [the error goes away](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b067872b0313e349) with an extra set of parentheses.

Comment: @sashoalm: Not really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is why one should use curly braces for initialization:

```
std::vector<char> buf { 
                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() 
                       };
```

In your case, `buf` is **not** an object — it is rather a function declaration. Search for *vexing parse in c++* to know the explanation why it is a function declaration.There are pretty much hundreds of topics on this.

---

Alright. Here is what happens to your code. This code:

```
 std::vector<char> buf(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

is seen by the compiler as function declaration, where:

- the function name is `buf` which returns`std::vector<char>`.
- it takes two parameters of types:

  - `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)`, which is just another way of writing `std::istreambuf_iterator<char> stream` (*parens are superfluous in this case*).
  - `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` which is a function type **again** (*parens are **not** superfluous in this case*) — which decays to a function pointer type, pointing to a function:

    - which takes nothing and return `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`

So your code becomes this:

```
std::vector<char>                         //return-type
buf                                       //function-name
(
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> stream,  //1st (named) parameter
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> (*)()    //2nd (unnamed) parameter
);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok, why does the following compile then: `std::vector<int> b;
 std::vector<int> a(b.begin(), b.end());
 if(a.size()) {
  return 1;
 }`

Comment: @iggy, That can't possibly be a function declaration. The other one could.

Comment: If using uniform initialization already, you can replace the second argument with `{}` :)

Comment: @chris what makes it different?

Comment: @iggy: Because in that case, object declaration is the *only possible* interpretation of the tokens used in the statement. In your question, the syntax could be interpreted to be  function declaration as well. And as such, the compilers are instructed by the language to give *function declaration* a preference whenever possible.

Comment: @Nawaz Could you please be a bit more specific? Both use iterator objects as arguments, so what is different?

Comment: @Nawaz I think OP is asking why that one can be interpreted as a function and not the other.

Comment: @iggy, You'll find more information when researching the most vexing parse. `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)` is a parameter `stream` of type `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` and `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` is an unnamed parameter of type pointer to function with no parameters and returning `std::istream_iterator<char>`. Since the entire thing can be interpreted as a function declaration, it is. `b.begin()` and `b.end()` aren't valid syntax to declare anything, so they are used as expressions in an object declaration.